# Dunford−Pettis property of $L^1(\mu)$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

$\def\bs#1{\boldsymbol#1}\def\sp{\kern.4mm}$Let $\bs K$ be either the standard real or complex topological field, and let $E$ be a Hausdorff locally convex space over $\bs K\sp$. Then saying that $E$ has the *Dunford−Pettis* property means that if we have any Banach space $F$ over $\bs K$ and any continuous linear map $u:E\to F$ such that for all bounded sets $B$ in $E$ we have $u\sp[\,B\,]$ relatively compact in $F_\sigma\,$, then for every absolutely convex compact set $K$ in $E_\sigma$ we have $u\sp[\,K\,]$ relatively compact in $F\sp$. Here $G_\sigma$ means the underlying vector space of $G$ equipped with the weak topology $\sigma(G,G')$ against the topological dual space.

If now $\mu$ is a positive measure on some set $\Omega\sp$, it is "well-known" that $L^1(\mu)$ has the Dunford−Pettis property. The standard reference book for this kind of matters is the first volume of Dunford and Schwartz' *Linear Operators* which I unfortunately do not have at hand. However, according to the information given by R. E. Edwards in his *Functional Analysis* this matter should be in Theorem VI.8.12 on page 508 that I didn't succeed to see by Google. I have a suspicion that there is the additional restriction that $\mu$ be $\sigma$−finite. Furthermore, in the references I have seen this matter considered, there is the restrictive assumption that $\mu$ be a Radon measure on some Hausdorff locally compact topological space.

Now **I am asking** whether there exist any publication where this $L^1(\mu)$ having the Dunford−Pettis property is proved for more general positive measures $\mu$ than referred to above$\sp$**?**

In particular, I am interested to know whether $L^1(\mu)$ has the Dunford−Pettis property in the case where $\mu$ is *almost decomposable* in the following sense: There are a "negligible" set $N'$ and a decomposition $\mathscr A$ of $\Omega\setminus N'$ into disjoint sets $A$ of (strictly) positive finite measure such that if we have any set $N''\subseteq\Omega$ with the property that $A\cap N''$ is included in some set $N_A$ of zero measure for all $A\in\mathscr A\sp$, then $N''$ is "negligible"; this meaning that $N''\cap B$ is included in some set, depending on $B$ and $N''$, of zero measure for all $B$ having finite measure.

**Added.** (8.12.2017) Having slept over the night, it suddenly occurred to me how the case of an *almost decomposable* positive measure is "trivially reduced" to the case of a $\sigma$-finite one. It confused me when Bill Johnson said that the "general" case could be reduced the "separable" case since there are even probability measures $\pi$ with $L^1(\pi)$ not separable. The "coin tossing" measure on $\Omega={}^{\mathbb R}\,\{\sp 0\sp, 1\sp\}$ is an example. The reduction can be done by using the "convergent sequences characterization" of the Dunford−Pettis property in the case of Banach spaces by observing that $L^1(\mu)$ is linearly homeomorphic to the $\ell^{\sp 1}\,$−sum of the family $\langle\sp L^1(\mu_A):A\in\mathscr A\sp\rangle$ when $\mu$ is almost decomposable. This solves the problem in the case of an almost decomposable positive measure.

Since at the moment I still do not have access to the book of Dunford and Schwartz, I would be grateful if in a comment someone, who has access, could confirm my suspicion that there the case of a general $\sigma$-finite positive measure is fully proved, and hence that there is no "Radon restriction". Furthermore, I am still interested to know if there possibly exists a reference where the case of positive measures that are more general than "almost decomposable" ones is considered.

Comment: It is trivial to reduce the general case to the case of separable $L_1$ spaces, and all of these are isomorphic to $L_1(0,1)$ or $\ell_1$, so what's the problem?

Comment: I do not see how to do that "trivial reduction", so could you give some details, possibly in the form of an answer?

Comment: Given a separable subspace $X$ of an $L_1$ space, let $Y$ be the smallest closed sublattice that contains $X$.  $Y$ is a separable abstract $L_1$ space and hence by Kakutani's representation theorem is an $L_1$ space. (You can avoid Kakutani's theorem, but it is a basic result.) See volume 2 of Lindenstrausr-Tzafriri.

Comment: @BillJohnson If I understand correctly your suggestion, having a sequence $\bs x$ in the original $L^1(\mu)$ you take as $X$ the linear span of it, and then we can identify $\bs x$ as being in a separable $L^1(\mu_1)$ for some other measure $\mu_1$ for which the Dunford−Pettis result is known to hold? In the mean time, the following occurred to me: Express every member of $\bs x$ as a limit of a sequence simple functions, and let $\mu_1$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the countably many "base" sets of these simple functions. Is $L^1(\mu_1)$ then separable?

Comment: @TaQ, you take the smallest closed lattice that contains your sequence; usually, this is strictly greater than the linear span but still separable. Certainly DP holds for $L_1$ (and $\ell_1$) and these are the only two Banach-space-isomorphism types of separable $L_1(\mu)$-spaces.

Comment: @TomekKania Yes, I think I understand that going through the application of Kakutani's representation theorem requires taking the smallest closed *lattice*. However, in the question at the end of my previous comment I wanted to know whether one could avoid using Kakutani's result by reducing the situation to the case of that $L^1(\mu_1)$ where at least $\mu_1$ is $\sigma$-finite but I do not know whether $L^1(\mu_1)$ is separable.

Comment: Yes, TaQ. Take $f_n$ dense in the unit ball of your subspace and work in $L_1(\nu)$ where $\nu :=\sum 2^{-n} |f_n| d \mu$. Here $\mu$ is the original measure, which can be anything, but $\nu$ is a finite measure.

Comment: @BillJohnson I have now independently figured out how to prove that my space $L^1(\mu_1)$ above indeed is separable, and it is also a simple matter to modify $\mu_1$ so that it becomes finite. However, I do not understand the purpose of  your construction of $\nu=\sum 2^{-n}|f_n|d\mu$ since it seems to me that the resulting $L_1(\nu)$ need not be separable, noting that it may contain as a subspace an $L^1$ over e.g. a big "coin tossing" space if $\mu$ and $f_n$ are suitably chosen. My $\mu_1$ avoids this since the underlying $\sigma$-algebra is suitably "weakened".

Comment: Oh, I meant that you could reduce to the case of a probability measure this way. This is what you asked in your comment. You can go further and reduce to the separable case by considering the smallest $\sigma$-algebra s.t. all functions in (a countable dense subset of) your separable subspace are measurable w.r.t. the $\sigma$-algebra and restricting $\vu$ to this $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I have now found W. Schachermayer's preprint *[A result of J. Bourgain: C (L1) has the Dunford—Pettis property](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~schachermayer/preprnts/prpr21.pdf)*   where the author completes and clarifies part of Bourgain's article *On the Dunford−Pettis property*. Although I have not yet checked the details, it seems to contain quite a detailed proof of $L^1(\pi)$ having the Dunford—Pettis property for an *arbitrary probability measure* $\pi\sp$.